# matplotlib: xticklabels out of border

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function which generates a figure with several bar subplots which share the x axis (on the bottom of the figure). The problem is that the xticks, set using **set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=60, fontsize=10)**, go out from the border of the figure (so the text is truncated). The command **plt.tight_layout()** run within the function is not helping. However, if I apply again plt.tight_layout() manually and after the figure is built then it works. This does not help much as I do not want to run the command manually. If within the code I run the command twice it does not help.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `matplotlib.rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})` when you import matplotlib instead of using `plt.tight_layout()`. This fixed some clipping issues I was having with the xticks of a plot.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! actually it seems that plt.autoscale() and plt.tight_layout() are not required any more in the code. You might want to use this as the answer so that I can accept it.